# sending 'live' photos to sms/mms

Tags: c#, twilio-api, mms

Using Twilio C# library for visual studio.  I can send sms without a problem, but I would like to send a quick, small snapshot of who-is-on-the-driveway when I send a driveway alert to my iPhone.

Docs seem to suggest that SendMessage() accepts a list of strings for media, except that it must be accessible online.

Is there no way to upload a picture or reference a local copy when I call SendMessage()? This is time-critical; if I don't have the snapshot within about 10-15 seconds after the driveway alert is triggered, they are already at my door.

Comment: You probably need to convert to a 64 bit stream so the picture is encoded as a string and then decode the image back from string  to binary picture.  But SMS stands for SHORT MESSAGE and the limit is : The maximum length of text message that you can send is 918 characters. However, if you send more than 160 characters then your message will be broken down in to chunks of 153 characters before being sent to the recipient’s handset.

Comment: right, but Twilio's SMS also accomodates media, making it more like SMS/MMS. Their MMS sample code sends a text message with a picture to my phone just fine; it's just that the picture itself has to have a URL and be available on the internet (as I understand it).

Comment: I think you wan MMS.  See : https://www.twilio.com/sms/features